# How to update a view during a CADisplayLink animation

Tags: swift, swiftui, cadisplaylink

I'm trying to implement a simple animation using `CADisplayLink`. A black square should move slowly across the screen.

But the square appears stationary because the `body` of `Squares` doesn't get updated when `step()` increments testX and testY.

From what I can gather (I'm new to Swift), I'm using the `@ObservedObject` paradigm correctly, so I don't understand why the view won't refresh.

How do I get `Squares`'s `body` to update along with the animation?

My code is below, thanks for your help!

```
class MyAnimations: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var testX: Double = 0
    @Published var testY: Double = 0
    
    func createDisplayLink() {
        let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(step))
        
        displaylink.add(to: .current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }
         
    @objc func step(link: CADisplayLink) {
        testX += 0.5
        testY += 0.5
    }
    
}



struct Squares: View {
    @ObservedObject var animation = MyAnimations()
    
    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: self.animation.testX, y: self.animation.testY, width: 50, height: 50))
        }
            .fill(Color.black)
    }
}


struct SomeOtherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Squares()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating the CADisplayLink anywhere? You need to get it going somewhere, such as adding the modifier  `.onAppear { self.animation.createDisplayLink() }` for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already calling createDisplayLink() from somewhere, sorry for the confusion. The animation runs, it's just that Squares() never updates.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** retested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5 - works as-is

This is because your `displaylink` is created on stack, so destroyed right after quit from function. You need to make it property.

Here is modified tested code. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
class MyAnimations: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var testX: Double = 0
    @Published var testY: Double = 0

    private var displaylink: CADisplayLink!       // << here !!
    func createDisplayLink() {
        if nil == displaylink {
            displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(step))
            displaylink.add(to: .current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        }
    }

    @objc func step(link: CADisplayLink) {
        testX += 0.5
        testY += 0.5
    }

}



struct Squares: View {
    @ObservedObject var animation = MyAnimations()

    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: self.animation.testX, y: self.animation.testY, width: 50, height: 50))
        }
        .fill(Color.black)
        .onAppear {
            animation.createDisplayLink()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me. How frustrating! I'm using Xcode 11.7 for iOS 13.6.